# Controlling NAO's joints using actionlib with nao_controller

Tags: ros, actionlib, nao-driver, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to both the NAO ROS package and actionlib, and I am trying to test if I can control the NAO's joints using the action goals in nao_controller.  I would like an example of how to form the goal object that is sent to the robot, i.e.:

```
client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('joint_trajectory', JointTrajectoryAction)
client.wait_for_server()
goal = ???
client.send_goal(goal)
client.wait_for_result()
```

Here is what I have been doing:

```
jt = JointAngleTrajectory()
jt.joint_names = ["HeadYaw", "HeadPitch"]
jt.joint_angles = [0, 0]
jt.times = [0.5, 0.5]
jtg = JointTrajectoryGoal()
jtg.trajectory = jt
jtag = JointTrajectoryActionGoal()
jtag.goal = jtg
client.send_goal(jtag)
```

But this gets me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'JointTrajectoryActionGoal' object has no attribute 'trajectory'
```

Could someone who has used nao_controller and/or actionlib before please clue me in on how to form this goal object?  It would be nice to have an example to generalize to other goals in nao_controller like JointAnglesWithSpeedActionGoal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31933/controlling-nao%27s-joints-using-actionlib-with-nao_controller/) by [greczek_USC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1883/greczek_usc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two nodes which already use the actionlib interface of nao_controller, you can have a look at them for example code: [nao_remote/pose_manager](http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/nao_common/nao_remote/scripts/pose_manager.py) to enter some default poses e.g. for teleoperation and [nao_driver/test_joint_angles](http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/nao_robot/nao_driver/scripts/test_joint_angles.py) to test nao_controller.

Here's the relevant code from test_joint_angles.py adjusted to your two joints:

```
goal = nao_msgs.msg.JointTrajectoryGoal()
goal.trajectory.joint_names = ["HeadYaw", "HeadPitch"]
point = JointTrajectoryPoint()
point.time_from_start = Duration(0.5)
point.positions = [0.0,0.0]
goal.trajectory.points = [point]
```

There are more examples in test_joint_angles.py, e.g. moving a single joint to multiple keypoints or moving multiple joints to multiple keypoints.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1